# Android RecyclerView and custom Adapter position elements changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a RecylcerView filled with a Custom Adapter `recylerView.setAdapter(myAdapter)`, and the adaper is filled with different elements by an `ArrayList`. In the ViewHolder i overrided the
`public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)` method. In the custom ViewHolder i put a button. The button has a click listener on it. When i click the button i read the variable `position` and i am facing that the variable changes every time i click the same button.
Why this happens?

My Adapter is like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify;
import com.amplifyframework.core.model.query.Where;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.Comments;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.Likes;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.Posts;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.internal.util.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread;

public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.PostViewHolder>
{
    private LinkedList<Posts> usersPostsList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Context context;
    //private Boolean likeChecker;
    private String currentUserId;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private int currentPosition;

    public PostsAdapter(Context context, String currentUserId, MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.currentUserId = currentUserId;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public PostsAdapter(LinkedList<Posts> usersPostsList, Context context)
    {
        this.usersPostsList = usersPostsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setMessages(LinkedList<Posts> usersPostsList) {
        this.usersPostsList = usersPostsList;
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;

        public static ImageButton LikePostButton, CommentPostButton;
        public TextView DisplayNoOfLikes, modifyPost;
        private TextView DisplayNoOfComments;
        String currentUserID;
        ExpandableTextView PostDescription;
        private Context context;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            this.context = context;

            LikePostButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
            CommentPostButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_button);
            DisplayNoOfLikes = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_likes);
            DisplayNoOfComments = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_comments);
            currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            modifyPost = mView.findViewById(R.id.modify_post);
        }



        public void setLikeButtonStatus(final String PostKey) {

            Amplify.DataStore.query(
                    Likes.class, Where.matches(Likes.POST_ID.eq(PostKey.trim()).and(Likes.SENDER.eq(currentUserID.trim()))),
                    items -> {
                        int countLikes = 0;
                        if (!items.hasNext()) {
                            LikePostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border);
                        }
                        while (items.hasNext()) {
                            Likes item = items.next();
                            countLikes++;
                            LikePostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_fill);
                            Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId());
                        }
                        int finalCountLikes = countLikes;
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setText(finalCountLikes + (" Likes"));
                    },
                    failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
            );

        }


        public void setFullname(String fullname)
        {
            TextView username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
            username.setText(fullname);
        }

        public void setProfileimage(Context ctx, String profileimage)
        {
            CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
            Amplify.Storage.getUrl(profileimage,
                    result -> {
                        URL url = result.getUrl();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Glide.with(ctx)
                                .load(url)
                                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                        .skipMemoryCache(true))
                                .into(image));
                    },
                    error -> Log.i("Amplify", "error while retrieving url"));
        }

        public void setTime(String time)
        {
            TextView PostTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
            PostTime.setText("   " + time);
        }
        public void setDate(String date)
        {
            TextView PostDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
            PostDate.setText("   " + date);
        }
        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            PostDescription = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
            PostDescription.setText(description);
        }


        public void setPostimage(Context ctx, String postimage, String id)
        {
            ImageView postImageInner = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

             Amplify.Storage.getUrl(postimage,
                    result -> {
                        URL url = result.getUrl();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Glide.with(ctx)
                                .load(url)
                                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                        .skipMemoryCache(true))
                                .into(postImageInner));
                        Log.i("Amplify---------", "url ok----");
                    },
                    error -> Log.e("Amplify---------", "error while retrieving url: " + error.getCause().toString()));

            postImageInner.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent clickPostIntent = new Intent(context, ClickPostActivity.class);
                clickPostIntent.putExtra("PostKey", id);
                clickPostIntent.putExtra("postImagePath", postimage);
                context.startActivity (clickPostIntent);
            });

        }
        public void setCountry(String country)
        {
            TextView CountryName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_country_name);
            CountryName.setText(country);
        }

        public void setCity(String city)
        {
            TextView City = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_city_name);
            City.setText("- " + city);
        }


        public void setCommentStatus(final String PostKey) {

            Amplify.DataStore.query(
                    Comments.class, Where.matches(Comments.POST_ID.eq(PostKey.trim())),
                    items -> {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (items.hasNext()) {
                            Comments comments = items.next();
                            i++;
                            int finalI = i;
                            runOnUiThread(() -> DisplayNoOfComments.setText(finalI + " comments"));
                            Log.i("amplify?", "comment id: " + comments.getId());
                        }
                    },
                    failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
            );
        }
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent,false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return new PostViewHolder(V, context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        currentPosition = position;
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.setFullname(usersPostsList.get(position).getFullname());
        viewHolder.setTime(usersPostsList.get(position).getTime());
        viewHolder.setDate(usersPostsList.get(position).getDate());
        viewHolder.setDescription(usersPostsList.get(position).getDescription());
        viewHolder.setProfileimage(context, usersPostsList.get(position).getProfileimage());
        viewHolder.setPostimage(context, usersPostsList.get(position).getPostimage(), usersPostsList.get(position).getId());
        viewHolder.setCountry(usersPostsList.get(position).getCountry());
        viewHolder.setCity(usersPostsList.get(position).getCity());


        if( viewHolder.PostDescription.originalText.length() > 100 ) {
            viewHolder.PostDescription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!((ExpandableTextView)v).read) {
                        ((ExpandableTextView)v).expandText();
                        ((ExpandableTextView)v).read = true;
                    } else {
                        ((ExpandableTextView)v).truncateText();
                        ((ExpandableTextView)v).read = false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }


        viewHolder.CommentPostButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent commentsIntent = new Intent(context, CommentActivity.class);
            commentsIntent.putExtra("PostKey",usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getId());
            context.startActivity(commentsIntent);
        });


        viewHolder.LikePostButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Amplify.DataStore.query(
                    Likes.class, Where.matches(Likes.POST_ID.eq(usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getId().trim())
                            .and(Likes.SENDER.eq(currentUserId.trim()))
                            .and((Likes.RECEIVER.eq(usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getUid())))
                    ),
                    items -> {
                        if (items.hasNext()) {
                            Likes item = items.next();
                            Amplify.DataStore.delete(item,
                                    deleted -> Log.i("Amplify", "Deleted item."),
                                    failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Delete failed.", failure)
                            );

                            Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId());
                        } else {
                            Likes likes = Likes.builder()
                                    .receiver(usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getUid().trim())
                                    .sender(currentUserId.trim())
                                    .postId(usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getId().trim())
                                    .value("true")
                                    .build();
                            Amplify.DataStore.save(
                                    likes,
                                    success -> Log.i("Amplify", "Item updated: " + success.item().getId()),
                                    error -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not save item to DataStore", error)
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    failure -> {
                        Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure);
                    }
            );
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        viewHolder.modifyPost.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClickPostActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("PostKey", usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getId());
            intent.putExtra("postImagePath", usersPostsList.get(currentPosition).getPostimage());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usersPostsList.size() ;
    }

}
```

Seems that method getItemViewType is called after the click on LikePostButton so that  : `viewHolder.LikePostButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {`  gets an older currentPosition variable value

Thanks to everyone helping me to understand

Comment: Please read the documentation of `onBindViewHolder` for your answer.

Comment: I read the documentation, thanks it was useful, i discovered that importing implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0' there is a mehod: viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition() that works well... Thanks @SteveM

Comment: but i did better with viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() and reversing the arraylist of the item before putting it in the adapter, because getAbsoluteAdapterPositions traverse the adapter elements positions on the contrary. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can override getItemViewType(position:Int) method and replace the line of super to return it with only position like this in Kotlin:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
```

in Java :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: This didn't help me unfortunately

Comment: can you share your adapter code to understand where the problem ?

Comment: in my adapter i set a global variable private in currentPosition;  ..... after i get the variable as :     @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        currentPosition = position;
        return position;
    }     then in my click listener in the method onBindViewHolder :    viewHolder.Button.setOnClickListener(v -> { list.get( currentPosition)..... but seems that the method getItemViewType is called after onBindViewHolder so the currentPosition variable is not updated

Comment: if I understand in the right way .. your problem is when you save the current position, you shouldn't use this variable (currentPosition) you can use the default position that inside onBindViewHolder so you shouldn't use the global variable

Comment: i cannot use the default position of onBindViewHolder the documentation says tha if you have a onClickListener the postition may be inaccurate and i faced it for real. I tryed what in the documentation is suggested so using getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() but it still fails, and also after about 5 or 6 clicks the method getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() returns -1, so it's a big problem for me...

Comment: Anyone knows if there is a GIT hub repository for the Recyclerview?

Comment: I got the problem.  the best way to do onClickListener you should implement it inside ViewHolder and to get the position you can use getAdapterPosition() so it will be like this : yourButton.setOnClickListener(this); and you should implement  the OnClick method and inside it you will check the id of the button then do what you want inside it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i solved it setting the listener on the button in the ViewHolder and then just calling `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` to get the correct position